# multiple x axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a sample data set

```
ID  Depth   Salinity    Temperature Time    fluorescence
1   0       1.3         29.2        13:44:23    152
2   3.1     1.4         29.2        13:44:26    175
3   3.5     2           29.2        13:44:30    149
4   4.3     2.6         29.2        13:44:34    192
5   7.5     2.9         29.4        13:44:37    174
6   8.2     2.1         29.1        13:44:41    154
7   10      2.6         29.1        13:44:44    147
8   9.1     2.6         29.1        13:44:48    150
9   7.3     2.7         28.9        13:44:52    147
10  5.2     3.2         29.0        13:44:55    180
11  4.5     2           29.0        13:44:59    167
12  3.3     2.3         29.1        13:45:03    154
13  2.5     1.8         29.1        13:45:06    106
14  0       1.5         29.1        13:45:10    136
```

I want two profiles Up and Down profile i.e. from depth 0-10 and 10-0 in a same plot. I used the code below to generate a plot

```
meltdf <-  mutate(meltdf, trend = c(rep("UP",7), rep("DOWN",7))) 
p <- ggplot(meltdf, aes(x = Temperature, y = Depth, color = trend)) + 
     geom_line()+
p
```

I get the plot with this. However, what I want is Depth in y axis and Salinity, Temperature, fluorescence in multiple x axis in the same graph. As they have varying ranges I don't know how i should set it.

Also the data i have is quite big and when i plot i dont get a smooth curve(pic [R plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amiYc.png)) in my result .Is there a way to avoid those spikes?

Comment: Putting x on depth and then adding `coord_flip` might fix the spikes (or use `geom_path`)

Comment: @RichardTelford flipping the axis works but as i mentioned i want depth on the yaxis and the 3 variables on y

Comment: There is a `sec.axis` argument to `scale_y_continuous`, but facets might be a better option.

Comment: @K.Maya I'm assuming you want to do this in order to see correlated trends among the three variables `Salinity, Temperature, fluorescence`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this

#### Your data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:14, Depth = c(0, 3.1, 3.5, 4.3, 7.5, 8.2, 
10, 9.1, 7.3, 5.2, 4.5, 3.3, 2.5, 0), Salinity = c(1.3, 1.4, 
2, 2.6, 2.9, 2.1, 2.6, 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 2, 2.3, 1.8, 1.5), Temperature = c(29.2, 
29.2, 29.2, 29.2, 29.4, 29.1, 29.1, 29.1, 28.9, 29, 29, 29.1, 
29.1, 29.1), Time = c("13:44:23", "13:44:26", "13:44:30", "13:44:34", 
"13:44:37", "13:44:41", "13:44:44", "13:44:48", "13:44:52", "13:44:55", 
"13:44:59", "13:45:03", "13:45:06", "13:45:10"), fluorescence = c(152L, 
175L, 149L, 192L, 174L, 154L, 147L, 150L, 147L, 180L, 167L, 154L, 
106L, 136L)), .Names = c("ID", "Depth", "Salinity", "Temperature", 
"Time", "fluorescence"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)
meltdf <-  mutate(df, trend = c(rep("UP",7), rep("DOWN",7)))
```

#### solution

Starting with `meltdf`, gather relevant x-axis variables

```
moremelt <- meltdf %>%
               gather(key, value, Salinity, Temperature, fluorescence)
```

`ggplot` with `facet_wrap` using options `nrow=3` and `scale="free"`

```
ggplot(moremelt, aes(x = value, y = Depth, color = interaction(trend,key), label=key)) + 
     geom_line(lwd=2) +
     scale_colour_manual(values=c("orange","red","blue","cyan","black","grey")) +
     facet_wrap(~key, nrow=3, scale="free")
```

Comment: thanks that was what i needed. Can i also manually set the x-axis limit for each of the variables? like `+ xlim(20, 40)` for temperature for example

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Do you mind asking as a separate question? I don't think it's an easy question but I could be wrong...